# how to force mvn redownload snapshot

Tags: maven, jenkins, dependencies, updates

I got a maven project (myApp) depending on another maven project in snapshot version.
like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.group.dep</groupId>
    <artifactId>arty</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

But I got a problem with this after the "arty" got an update without changing the version (I know that would be the cleanest solution).
I build the myApp local and got still the old version of the "arty" dependency.

I verified tow option working for me (and a college):
1) Manual cleaning of the local repository: navigating to my `.m2/repo/org/group/dep/arty` and deleted all folders inside. After rebuilding the myApp local it was working fine - arty was downloaded form the artifactory.company.com again with the updated content.

2) Local building of the arty package so it got updated in the local repository. After rebuilding the myApp local it was working fine.

But I got similar problem on the Jenkins:
I got a Jenkins job just building `org.group.myApp` without building before `org.group.dep.arty`.  It failed for the missing changes form "arty".

What can I do now to solve my problem there?
I can not rely on first building `org.group.dep.arty` as I can not be sure for Jenkins to run both jobs on the same host using same local repository (I don't want to change that).
Somehow the myApp-Jobs was failing after I manually cleared on that Jenkins node the `org.group.dep.arty` in the repository and running than the myApp-job (was somehow not downloading the package).

I finally found the `mvn -u` but as I tried this I was as well disappointed. 
I tried different maven versions on that jenkins and got the same result.
Is there no way to force the update of the snapshot versions?

Answer (score 2):

Is this "another project" is a part of the same multi-module project? 
If so you can build your project with `--also-make` options so that maven will effectively rebuild your module and all of its dependencies

If its an entirely different project, use `mvn -U` to forcefully download **all** the snapshot dependencies of your project.

If there is a particular issue with one concrete dependency consider using `mvn dependency:get`. This `get` goal of `maven-dependency-plugin` downloads one specific artifact from the remote repository

[Here is a link to the plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html)

Comment: It should not be part of multi-module (part of more then one, ... unhappy constellation as developed over years, hopefully get rid of this, but other topic) unfortunately it seems that the -U parameter is simply not working correctly - the snapshot do not get updated on my Jenkins when using this. Maybe the dependency:get would work, but I've this would be obviously more work.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to redownload `-SNAPSHOT` is by using the command line option: `-U` or as long option `--update-snapshots`

Furthermore your project sounds like the need for a multi module build which prevents such issues. Or you might need to define those Jobs depending on each other (There is an option to build if a SNAPSHOT has been updated in Jenkins).